# issue with drop down box in zeppelin view

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am using zeppelin for some visualization, Currently I am using checkbox for multiple option selection like below

select ${checkbox:Mobile Type = "Apple", "Samsung"|"LG"|"Other" } from "mobile_usage"

Instead of checkbox I need to add drop-down box due to some requirement region, is there is any way to add drop-down box , my requirement is to select an column from the drop-down and run the query for that . Please help

Comment: Could u attach screenshots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add a drop-down selection for your query by simply modifying it to this:

```
select ${Mobile Type = Apple,Apple|Samsung|LG|Other} from mobile_usage
```

For more details about dynamic forms in Zeppelin, refer this link:
https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/manual/dynamicform.html#select-form